# Sleeping in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

In my Rails controller method, which is executed when the user submits a form, there is a Ruby code `sleep(60)`, telling it to wait for a minute. One user submits the form, and while the execution is "sleeping", another user submits the form. Will the second user have to wait for the first user to finish, or will the execution of the controller start for the second user?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both users will wait for 60 seconds only, they will not depend on each other.
As request will be processed separately for each other.
Hence no dependency

Comment: With the caveat that if the rails server is single threaded (ie. Webrick) then the second user will have to wait for the first user's request to completely finish before it can start.

Comment: Yes rightly said, if a server is sinlge threaded, then it wont be entertaining both request at a time, hence second user's request will be entertained after former one is finished